# Error generating next.js images path in export

Tags: next.js

I'm starting my studies in Next.js and managed to develop a relatively simple website, my problems started when I did a next export to make the website available on my client's hosting.

The problem is with the image paths. My settings are these:

**File next.config.js**

```
module.exports = ({
  basePath: '/sitenext'
}
```

**My image**

```
<Image
  src="/assets/images/logo.webp"
  alt="Logo"
  width={96}
  height={116}
/>
```

**The path of the image generated in HTML is this**

```
/_next/image?url=%2Fassets%2Fimages%2Flogo.webp&w=384&q=75
```

After configuring basePath,  works perfectly, only images that have not loaded correctly.

I also tried the root of the host and was also unsuccessful.
Locally everything works perfectly in both dev and start mode.
Thanks a lot for the help